# Spawning Quicktime in a Sandboxed Mac App

Tags: objective-c, macos, quicktime, launching-application, appstore-sandbox

I had asked a previous question about an issue I was having with AVPlayerView. After toying with it a bit, I actually like my mac app looks and runs a lot better when, instead of opening a new window with an AVPlayerView, it launches QuickTime, and tells it to open my http url of a video. I have come up with a few ways to do this, all of which work without sandboxing and none of which work with. I am currently using an NSTask to essentially

```
open -a "Quicktime Player" "http://example.com/video.m4v"
```

Again, this works, but only when my app is not sandboxed. Is there any way to do this in a sandboxed app?
Thanks in advance for any input  or suggestions.

Comment: did my answer help you find a solution? if yes, I'd be thankful if you accept it using the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox doesn't allow to work with NSTask by default. Use the [appropriate entitlement.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW1)

To open quicktime and start playing a movie you're probably better off using [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/openURLs:withAppBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifiers:) like this:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURLs:@[url]
                withAppBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX"
                                options:NSWorkspaceLaunchAsync
         additionalEventParamDescriptor:NULL
                      launchIdentifiers:nil];
```

Alternatively go straight down to [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/LSLaunchURLSpec) where you even have more control of what and how things are launched:

```
NSURL *appToOpenWith = // get the URL of Quicktime using NSWorkspace URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier;
LSLaunchURLSpec inLaunchSpec;

inLaunchSpec.appURL = (__bridge CFURLRef) appToOpenWith;
inLaunchSpec.itemURLs =  (__bridge CFArrayRef) ([NSArray arrayWithObject:theNSURLPointingToYourM4V ]);
inLaunchSpec.passThruParams = NULL;
inLaunchSpec.launchFlags = kLSLaunchDefaults;  // could be done async... are we here in the main thread?
inLaunchSpec.asyncRefCon = NULL;

CFURLRef outLaunchedURL;
OSStatus diditOpen = LSOpenFromURLSpec (&inLaunchSpec, &outLaunchedURL);
if (noErr != diditOpen) {
    NSLog(@"couldn't open selected items with error: %i", diditOpen);
} else {
    NSLog(@"opened with: %@", [(__bridge NSURL*)outLaunchedURL description]);
}
```